# My code is formatted but Stack Overflow complains that it is unformatted

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, editor

I tried to post a question on SO.

The preview of the post is:

[image: Output]

And my code segments are:

[image: Code 2]

[image: Code 3]

I found everything correct, but SO refused to post the question as asked me indent the code by four spaces (even I did that).

This is so frustrating and I spent nearly an hour to resolve the formatting, but I couldn't.

Comment: You can use ``` (triple `) even around output and error messages. Easier to handle than manually ensuring 4 leading spaces each line.

Comment: Is this using the new wizard? or the old one. Looks like the old one,

Comment: I assume you have "[1]:link, [2]:link, [3]:link", separated by one line break each at the bottom. Try adding an additional line between each. If that doesn't work, add line breaks in the text where you have the links ("[here][1]").

Comment: @qrsngky Please don't recommend users put code fences around error messages. They should put them in block quotes instead and only use single backticks around parts of the error message that are code.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the entire body of the input box(es) showing you the error message? Or include it here in your meta post? It will be difficult to

Comment: @TylerH **strongly** disagree WRT formatting error messages. There is extremely well established precedent for formatting them like code, which makes them *look like they do in the terminal*. There are **several** environments that attempt to take advantage of the entire error message being monospaced - in particular, Python 3.10 and up will show code in a traceback and *attempt to highlight part of the line* by "underlining" it with `^` symbols on the next line. Before that, it would still use a single `^` to try to "point at" a spot in the line. It also indents lines in a stack trace.

Comment: Also WRT Python, it is **very** common to show examples as a REPL session, in which case an exception might be intermingled with code, and lines of code may be prefixed with `>>> ` and `... `. Trying to reformat that according to your proposal would be a lot of work for, in my view, a net loss in clarity.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Error messages, in general, are not code; they are prose, so they should not be tagged with code backticks. I and many others have been revising posts and passing guidance this way for _years_ on the site. In some cases there are error messages that do _contain_ code or that are only ever shown _in a code environment_; as my comment above mentioned, such cases can and should include code backticks around them.

Comment: I've lost count of the times that OP tried to format a Python stack trace as a block quote and made an unreadable mess out of it. When this happens, it is tedious-to-nearly-impossible to recover the intended appearance.

Comment: In response to your specific example, stack traces (in any language) are usually an exception to the "use block quote formatting for error messages". But the vast majority of error messages are not stack traces. In fact I would argue that stack traces are not actually error messages, but more akin to logs.

Comment: "In some cases there are error messages that do contain code *or that are only ever shown in a code environment*" - Unless the error was in a modal dialog created by an IDE or a JavaScript alert, I fail to see how that ever *isn't* the case.

Comment: "But the vast majority of error messages are not stack traces. In fact I would argue that stack traces are not actually error messages, but more akin to logs." I *genuinely can't even imagine an example of what you have in mind.* But even when the problem *actually is* being exhibited with an unexpected log message, rather than an error *per se* - it is still common for log messages to be deliberately formatted with the assumption that they will be displayed in a monospace font, i.e., using fixed-width "columns".

Comment: I believe it's due to the "my file is [here]" links. I think you've typed single line breaks between those lines, which aren't rendered in the rendered post, and that combined with the brackets is causing that part to be recognized as code. Try putting a second line break (i.e., an empty line) between each of those links and see if that works.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Perhaps both your and TylerH's views on these matters are colored a wee bit by the development environments you work with daily? Python apparently is geared toward being compiled in an environment using a monospaced font. So, if you are answering questions in [python], by all means, use code formatting instead of blockquote (or use both [e.g., ``> ``` ``]) In general, however, the expectation is that error messages are in blockquotes (as you are quoting the system reporting the error).